# Why are my snake's belly scales turning yellow?

Tags: health, diseases, snakes, terrariums

I recently took my snake out of his cage to hold him for a bit but I noticed a light yellow on his belly. He has checker like scales with some black and some white (those colored scales were on him when I bought him). I don't know how he got this but I have a feeling he has ammonia on his scales from liquid. I couldn't find anything on the web that cures ammonia for snakes.

[image: Corn snake with ammonia]

The image above shows yellow on the top of the corn snakes body. My corn snake has the same colored yellow but on his belly (bottom of his body). His tank size is about 34 inches long, 26 inches wide, and 41 inches tall. His everyday temps range from 74 degrees to 85 degrees. I don't use substrate for him because he may swallow some by accident so I use those flat tank mats. He eats small rats every Wednesday.

[image: Snake mat for snake tanks]

The image above is what his mat looks like except that his mat is green and fits the length and width on bottom floor of his tank. The heating pad is located to the far left end side of the tank. He will go over there if he feels like it. My day lamp sit on the top far right of the lid and my night lamp goes to the same spot. I switch between the two lamps and the heating pad normally don't get turned on that often unless needed. I don't turn on day lamp in daytime unless too cool in tank. I don't turn turn on night lamp until night time and the night lamp has concentrated heat that focuses on a particular area.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

K so I looked at some research and I found out that you're housing your pet incorrectly.

> Blister Disease
>   Blister disease occurs when a corn snake is housed incorrectly. It is caused by bacteria on the skin and scales, brought on by dirty living conditions and high humidity levels in a terrarium. If a snake has developed blister disease, the scales on his belly will turn yellow or brown, and he will develop a series of tiny white or yellow bumps. If left untreated, these bumps can quickly turn into lesions, open sores, and pustules, and recovery is unlikely at this point.
>   If your snake develops signs of blister disease, a thorough terrarium cleaning is necessary. Remove all substrate, sterilize the entire terrarium, and move your corn snake into a hospital tank. You should also bathe him in warm water and put hydrogen peroxide on the infected areas. If this treatment is unsuccessful and his symptoms worsen, a trip to the vet is pertinent.
>   From: http://www.petuniversity.com/reptiles/snakes/species/corn-snakes/health-care.htm
>
> Blister Disease
>   Blister Disease can be avoided with proper husbandry, so make sure that you are providing the proper environment for your pet snake. Fluid-filled blisters will usually form on the underside of the snake when housed in dirty, moldy, and/or overly moist substrate. Don't mistake these blisters with burn blisters; these blisters may form a few at first but will quickly grow in number and become life threatening especially if they spread near the mouth, nose, or cloaca.
>   The best treatment is to prevent it from developing. Keep the substrate clean and dray. Make sure to remove feces and urates. Frequently change the bedding. You can treat a one or two blisters at home by sterilizing a needle and piercing the blister; use a clean cotton swab or a bandage to absorb the fluid. Make sure to fluid the blisters twice a day with betadine or hydrogen peroxide and apply an antibiotic ointment. House the snake in a quarantine tank with paper towels until the blisters have healed.
>   If there are multiple blisters and/or blisters that are in sensitive areas, consult a reputable vet asap.
>   From: http://whitney05.hubpages.com/hub/Common-Health-Problems-Snakes

Comment: I had took the snake to an exotic vet a long while ago. They recommended cleaning his tank with bleach and detergent to kill the germs. He's alright now.

Comment: k sounds good. But in my research I never found anything like that.

Comment: There wasn't any mention of blisters, or any types of sores on the snake, just discoloration. I don't think the snakes has blister disease.

Comment: @MattS. he probably didn't know about the blister disease. He probably just saw the discoloration and this is the reason why it happened

Answer (score 0):

Some snakes develop different patterns as they grow, does it look like a pattern or disease? My snake is a type of Amel, or Albino. She has a light yellowish tint to her in certain places that are a patternings.

Also, make sure you are using the right substrate. Aspen shavings are the correct substrate, not Cedar or Pine. Make sure your snake doesn't have mites too, and check in with the vet for any scale rot that could be forming if you are worried about that.

Comment: do you have any source for your patterns change statement a link maybe? it will improve this answer a lot.